# How to fetch using dulwich in python

Tags: python, git, dulwich

I'm trying to do the equivalent of `git fetch -a` using the dulwich library within python.

Using the docs at https://www.dulwich.io/docs/tutorial/remote.html I created the following script:

```
from dulwich.client import LocalGitClient
from dulwich.repo import Repo
import os

home = os.path.expanduser('~')

local_folder = os.path.join(home, 'temp/local'
local = Repo(local_folder)

remote = os.path.join(home, 'temp/remote')

remote_refs = LocalGitClient().fetch(remote, local)
local_refs = LocalGitClient().get_refs(local_folder)

print(remote_refs)
print(local_refs)
```

with an existing git repository at `~/temp/remote` and a newly initialised repo at `~/temp/local`

`remote_refs` shows everything I would expect, but `local_refs` is an empty dictionary and `git branch -a` on the local repo returns nothing.

Am I missing something obvious?

This is on dulwich 0.12.0 and Python 3.5

**EDIT #1**

Following a discussion on the python-uk irc channel, I updated my script to include the use of `determine_wants_all`:

```
from dulwich.client import LocalGitClient
from dulwich.repo import Repo

home = os.path.expanduser('~')

local_folder = os.path.join(home, 'temp/local'
local = Repo(local_folder)

remote = os.path.join(home, 'temp/remote')

wants = local.object_store.determine_wants_all
remote_refs = LocalGitClient().fetch(remote, local, wants)
local_refs = LocalGitClient().get_refs(local_folder)

print(remote_refs)
print(local_refs)
```

but this had no effect :-(

**EDIT #2**

Again, following discussion on the python-uk irc channel, I tried running `dulwich fetch` from within the local repo. It gave the same result as my script i.e. the remote refs were printed to the console correctly, but `git branch -a` showed nothing.

**EDIT - Solved**

A simple loop to update the local refs did the trick:

```
from dulwich.client import LocalGitClient
from dulwich.repo import Repo
import os

home = os.path.expanduser('~')

local_folder = os.path.join(home, 'temp/local')
local = Repo(local_folder)

remote = os.path.join(home, 'temp/remote')
remote_refs = LocalGitClient().fetch(remote, local)

for key, value in remote_refs.items():
    local.refs[key] = value

local_refs = LocalGitClient().get_refs(local_folder)

print(remote_refs)
print(local_refs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalGitClient.fetch() does not update refs, it just fetches objects and then returns the remote refs so you can use that to update the target repository refs.

Comment: Thanks to this answer from jelmer, his assistance on the dulwich irc channel and the code for porcelain.pull here: https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/master/dulwich/porcelain.py, I've managed to solve this. I'll edit the question with my solution